# Fullcalendar scheduler retrieving resources using JSON feed

Tags: json, fullcalendar

I've just started using the Scheduler add-on for Jquery Full Calendar, but having issues retrieving the resources as a JSON feed, which is necessary as they are taken from a database. Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.6.2/demos/scale.html

Basically, the resources are the names down the left side, but for my calendar I will always need the parent -> children view as I have properties with units within them.

Currently, I am getting the data from the database as required and this is the array I get (and bear in mind that these are just totally random examples for my testing only):

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [title] => Emerson Buildings
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 7
                        [title] => Michael
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 10
                        [title] => Unit 2
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [title] => Morb House
        [children] => Array
            (
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 5
                        [title] => Apartment Number 1
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 6
                        [title] => 2 Bed Apartment
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 11
                        [title] => Jamie
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

And when I convert to JSON after retrieving these resources I save it to a file which I get using my `get-resources.php`:

```
<?php
// Require our Event class and datetime utilities
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/utils.php';

// Read and parse our events JSON file into an array of event data arrays.
$json = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/booking_json/resources.json');

// Send JSON to the client.
echo $json;
```

The JSON in the resources.json file:

```
[{"id":3,"title":"Emerson Buildings","children":[{"id":7,"title":"Michael"},{"id":10,"title":"Unit 2"}]},{"id":2,"title":"Morb House","children":{"2":{"id":5,"title":"Apartment Number 1"},"3":{"id":6,"title":"2 Bed Apartment"},"4":{"id":11,"title":"Jamie"}}}]
```

However, this always throws the exception error when attempting to retrieve it in the javascript initialisation:

```
$('#availability-calendar').fullCalendar( {
    schedulerLicenseKey: '0409344942-fcs-1497004132',
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaDay,agendaWeek'
    },
    defaultDate: TODAY,
    defaultView: 'timelineMonth',
    editable: true,
    navLinks: true,
    eventLimit: true,
    timeFormat: 'hh:mma',
    resourceAreaWidth: '25%',
    resourceLabelText: 'Property / Units',
    resources: {
        url: '/get-resources.php',
        error: function() {
            $('#resource-warning').show();
        }
    },
    events: {
        url: '/get-bookings.php',
        error: function() {
            $('#script-warning').show();
        }
    },
    loading: function(bool) {
        $('#loading').toggle(bool);
    },
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
    }
});
```

(specifically referring here to the resources part). Just to clarify, I'm getting the bookings in pretty much the same way but since there are no nested values like the resources, they work.

Any help on this is appreciated as the documentation on the Full Calendar website does not really go into detail about this method.

EDIT: I have managed to fix it. Basically it was the way the children were being formatted in the string, so I now do this:

```
foreach ($prop_units as $v) {
    $id = $v['prop_id'];
    $record = array_diff_key($v, $exclude);

    if (!isset($result[$id])) {
        $result[$id] = $record;
        $result[$id]['units'] = [];
    }

    $unit = array_diff_key($v, $record);
    $result[$id]['units'][$x]['id'] = $unit['unit_id'];
    $result[$id]['units'][$x]['title'] = $unit['unitName'];
    $x ++;
}


if (!empty($result)) {

    $resources = array();
    foreach ($result as $propId => $row) {
        $resource = array();
        $resource['id'] = $propId;
        $resource['title'] = $row['propertyName'];
        $resource['children'] = [ ];

        foreach($row['units'] as $unit_row) {
            array_push($resource['children'],(object) $unit_row);
        }

        $obj = (object) $resource;

        array_push($resources, $obj);

        $obj = false;
    }
}
```

The main change being that instead of assigning the unit array to the children part of the `$resource` object, I now loop through each one and `array_push()` it in. This then returns the JSON in the correct format allowing it to render correctly. Thanks to @ADyson for helping with this.

Comment: "after retrieving these resources I save it to a file which I get using my get-resources.php:". Why not have get-resources.php retrieve the data directly? That should save time and effort. Anyway, the "children" of the second resource are in the wrong JSON format.

Comment: It needs to be more like `"children": [
  {
   "id": 5,
   "title": "Apartment Number 1"
  },
  {
   "id": 6,
   "title": "2 Bed Apartment"
  },
  {
   "id": 11,
   "title": "Jamie"
  }
 ]`

Comment: Yes I agree about the second set of children not being correct. I did analyse it further - but I don't understand why it's doing that. I have it bringing out the first set now but the second property has no children...

Comment: If you show the code where you're building the whole resources array in PHP it might be fixable.

Comment: Hi, I've actually just managed to figure out the way to do it, based on your deduction regarding the incorrect format. Seems that because each unit array was separate, it was adding the ID in before each child. So if you see in my question I've added the solution.

Comment: that's great, glad to have been of some help. I would still suggest that you could tell "get-resources.php" to directly query the database for the resource data, rather than putting it in a file first and then reading that. It seems an unnecessary intermediate step, unless there's something about your architecture that is not explained here which would require it.

Comment: I'm using Symfony, and the get-resources.php is not directly callable, and I don't need them on the home page - so I just do the code in the controller which writes the file ready for retrieving on the calendar page.